# Jenkins Jcloud Opensatck error

Tags: jenkins, jclouds, openstack-nova

Hi i m getting the follwing error when i tried to provision a slave on Opensatck.
The Slave gets created on openstack but it destroys it with following exception

Error while serving http://localhost:8081/cloud/fedora/provision
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:298)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:161)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:96)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:121)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:249)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1494)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:123)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:114)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
        at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:48)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
        at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
        at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1474)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:533)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:960)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1021)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
        at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jclouds.compute.RunNodesException: error running 1 node group(ubuntu) location(RegionOne) image(bf68af6f-e6a1-43f6-8ff7-25b54d257fe8) size(2) options({loginUser=ubuntu, loginPasswordPresent=true, loginPrivateKeyPresent=true, scriptPresent=true, securityGroups=[default], userMetadata={Name=ubuntu}, autoAssignFloatingIp=false, keyPairName=pub, userData=[B@7c1521, configDrive=false})
    Execution failures:

```
0 error[s]
Node failures:

1) NoSuchElementException on node RegionOne/873b9f1f-8c3b-41c1-9590-c85ba0bd39c7:
java.util.NoSuchElementException: could not connect to any ip address port 22 on node {id=RegionOne/873b9f1f-8c3b-41c1-9590-c85ba0bd39c7, providerId=873b9f1f-8c3b-41c1-9590-c85ba0bd39c7, uri=http://172.27.59.30:8774/v2/98e76fc602cc4a2ca945ff7140a4c1a5/servers/873b9f1f-8c3b-41c1-9590-c85ba0bd39c7, name=ubuntu-d64, uri=http://172.27.59.30:8774/v2/98e76fc602cc4a2ca945ff7140a4c1a5/servers/873b9f1f-8c3b-41c1-9590-c85ba0bd39c7, location={scope=HOST, id=049edc6318675e518ceb2b7b4628dc2d680176680f59204d452b8314, description=049edc6318675e518ceb2b7b4628dc2d680176680f59204d452b8314, parent=RegionOne}, group=ubuntu, imageId=RegionOne/bf68af6f-e6a1-43f6-8ff7-25b54d257fe8, os={family=unrecognized, name=Ubuntu-14.04, description=Ubuntu-14.04, is64Bit=true}, status=RUNNING, loginPort=22, hostname=ubuntu-d64, privateAddresses=[10.0.0.2], hardware={id=RegionOne/2, providerId=2, name=m1.small, location={scope=ZONE, id=RegionOne, description=RegionOne, parent=openstack-nova}, processors=[{cores=1.0, speed=1.0}], ram=2048, volumes=[{type=LOCAL, size=20.0, bootDevice=true, durable=true}], supportsImage=ALWAYS_TRUE}, loginUser=ubuntu, userMetadata={Name=ubuntu, jclouds-group=ubuntu}}
    at org.jclouds.compute.util.ConcurrentOpenSocketFinder.findOpenSocketOnNode(ConcurrentOpenSocketFinder.java:107)
    at org.jclouds.compute.functions.CreateSshClientOncePortIsListeningOnNode.apply(CreateSshClientOncePortIsListeningOnNode.java:71)
    at org.jclouds.compute.functions.CreateSshClientOncePortIsListeningOnNode.apply(CreateSshClientOncePortIsListeningOnNode.java:45)
    at org.jclouds.compute.callables.SudoAwareInitManager.init(SudoAwareInitManager.java:71)
    at org.jclouds.compute.callables.RunScriptOnNodeAsInitScriptUsingSsh.init(RunScriptOnNodeAsInitScriptUsingSsh.java:68)
    at org.jclouds.compute.callables.RunScriptOnNodeAsInitScriptUsingSshAndBlockUntilComplete.init(RunScriptOnNodeAsInitScriptUsingSshAndBlockUntilComplete.java:81)
    at org.jclouds.compute.callables.RunScriptOnNodeAsInitScriptUsingSshAndBlockUntilComplete.init(RunScriptOnNodeAsInitScriptUsingSshAndBlockUntilComplete.java:42)
    at org.jclouds.compute.strategy.InitializeRunScriptOnNodeOrPlaceInBadMap.call(InitializeRunScriptOnNodeOrPlaceInBadMap.java:65)
    at org.jclouds.compute.strategy.InitializeRunScriptOnNodeOrPlaceInBadMap.call(InitializeRunScriptOnNodeOrPlaceInBadMap.java:38)
    at org.jclouds.compute.strategy.CustomizeNodeAndAddToGoodMapOrPutExceptionIntoBadMap.call(CustomizeNodeAndAddToGoodMapOrPutExceptionIntoBadMap.java:123)
    at org.jclouds.compute.strategy.CustomizeNodeAndAddToGoodMapOrPutExceptionIntoBadMap.apply(CustomizeNodeAndAddToGoodMapOrPutExceptionIntoBadMap.java:146)
    at org.jclouds.compute.strategy.CustomizeNodeAndAddToGoodMapOrPutExceptionIntoBadMap.apply(CustomizeNodeAndAddToGoodMapOrPutExceptionIntoBadMap.java:53)
    at shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$1.apply(Futures.java:711)
    at shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$ChainingListenableFuture.run(Futures.java:849)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


1 error[s]
    at shaded.com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:160)
    at jenkins.plugins.jclouds.compute.JCloudsSlaveTemplate.destroyBadNodesAndPropagate(JCloudsSlaveTemplate.java:347)
    at jenkins.plugins.jclouds.compute.JCloudsSlaveTemplate.get(JCloudsSlaveTemplate.java:336)
    at jenkins.plugins.jclouds.compute.JCloudsSlaveTemplate.provisionSlave(JCloudsSlaveTemplate.java:191)
    at jenkins.plugins.jclouds.compute.JCloudsCloud.doProvision(JCloudsCloud.java:281)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: org.jclouds.compute.RunNodesException: error running 1 node group(ubuntu) location(RegionOne) image(bf68af6f-e6a1-43f6-8ff7-25b54d257fe8) size(2) options({loginUser=ubuntu, loginPasswordPresent=true, loginPrivateKeyPresent=true, scriptPresent=true, securityGroups=[default], userMetadata={Name=ubuntu}, autoAssignFloatingIp=false, keyPairName=pub, userData=[B@7c1521, configDrive=false})
Execution failures:

0 error[s]
Node failures:

1) NoSuchElementException on node RegionOne/873b9f1f-8c3b-41c1-9590-c85ba0bd39c7:
java.util.NoSuchElementException: could not connect to any ip address port 22 on node {id=RegionOne/873b9f1f-8c3b-41c1-9590-c85ba0bd39c7, providerId=873b9f1f-8c3b-41c1-9590-c85ba0bd39c7, uri=http://172.27.59.30:8774/v2/98e76fc602cc4a2ca945ff7140a4c1a5/servers/873b9f1f-8c3b-41c1-9590-c85ba0bd39c7, name=ubuntu-d64, uri=http://172.27.59.30:8774/v2/98e76fc602cc4a2ca945ff7140a4c1a5/servers/873b9f1f-8c3b-41c1-9590-c85ba0bd39c7, location={scope=HOST, id=049edc6318675e518ceb2b7b4628dc2d680176680f59204d452b8314, description=049edc6318675e518ceb2b7b4628dc2d680176680f59204d452b8314, parent=RegionOne}, group=ubuntu, imageId=RegionOne/bf68af6f-e6a1-43f6-8ff7-25b54d257fe8, os={family=unrecognized, name=Ubuntu-14.04, description=Ubuntu-14.04, is64Bit=true}, status=RUNNING, loginPort=22, hostname=ubuntu-d64, privateAddresses=[10.0.0.2], hardware={id=RegionOne/2, providerId=2, name=m1.small, location={scope=ZONE, id=RegionOne, description=RegionOne, parent=openstack-nova}, processors=[{cores=1.0, speed=1.0}], ram=2048, volumes=[{type=LOCAL, size=20.0, bootDevice=true, durable=true}], supportsImage=ALWAYS_TRUE}, loginUser=ubuntu, userMetadata={Name=ubuntu, jclouds-group=ubuntu}}
    at org.jclouds.compute.util.ConcurrentOpenSocketFinder.findOpenSocketOnNode(ConcurrentOpenSocketFinder.java:107)
    at org.jclouds.compute.functions.CreateSshClientOncePortIsListeningOnNode.apply(CreateSshClientOncePortIsListeningOnNode.java:71)
    at org.jclouds.compute.functions.CreateSshClientOncePortIsListeningOnNode.apply(CreateSshClientOncePortIsListeningOnNode.java:45)
    at org.jclouds.compute.callables.SudoAwareInitManager.init(SudoAwareInitManager.java:71)
    at org.jclouds.compute.callables.RunScriptOnNodeAsInitScriptUsingSsh.init(RunScriptOnNodeAsInitScriptUsingSsh.java:68)
    at org.jclouds.compute.callables.RunScriptOnNodeAsInitScriptUsingSshAndBlockUntilComplete.init(RunScriptOnNodeAsInitScriptUsingSshAndBlockUntilComplete.java:81)
    at org.jclouds.compute.callables.RunScriptOnNodeAsInitScriptUsingSshAndBlockUntilComplete.init(RunScriptOnNodeAsInitScriptUsingSshAndBlockUntilComplete.java:42)
    at org.jclouds.compute.strategy.InitializeRunScriptOnNodeOrPlaceInBadMap.call(InitializeRunScriptOnNodeOrPlaceInBadMap.java:65)
    at org.jclouds.compute.strategy.InitializeRunScriptOnNodeOrPlaceInBadMap.call(InitializeRunScriptOnNodeOrPlaceInBadMap.java:38)
    at org.jclouds.compute.strategy.CustomizeNodeAndAddToGoodMapOrPutExceptionIntoBadMap.call(CustomizeNodeAndAddToGoodMapOrPutExceptionIntoBadMap.java:123)
    at org.jclouds.compute.strategy.CustomizeNodeAndAddToGoodMapOrPutExceptionIntoBadMap.apply(CustomizeNodeAndAddToGoodMapOrPutExceptionIntoBadMap.java:146)
    at org.jclouds.compute.strategy.CustomizeNodeAndAddToGoodMapOrPutExceptionIntoBadMap.apply(CustomizeNodeAndAddToGoodMapOrPutExceptionIntoBadMap.java:53)
    at shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$1.apply(Futures.java:711)
    at shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$ChainingListenableFuture.run(Futures.java:849)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


1 error[s]
    at org.jclouds.compute.internal.BaseComputeService.createNodesInGroup(BaseComputeService.java:227)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(DelegatingInvocationHandler.java:40)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy90.createNodesInGroup(Unknown Source)
    at jenkins.plugins.jclouds.compute.JCloudsSlaveTemplate.get(JCloudsSlaveTemplate.java:334)
    ... 60 more
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems jclouds could not ssh into your machine. Does your image support SSH by default? Alternatively it might be a network issue.